# Unable to focus on a checkbox with tabindex

Tags: css, html

I am unable to focus on a checkbox with tabindex=0. I think this is due to display and opacity setting

```
.newCheckbox input[type=checkbox] {
   display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I also have a label before the checkbox. Is it possible to change the code to make the checkbox label appear highlighed - to give an appearance as if the checkbox is highlighted on tab.

plunkr -     https://plnkr.co/edit/6ecZu1G8tKzztGGbK4G3?p=preview

Comment: Your checkbox is invisible because you have `opacity: 0` on it. The checkbox next to the button is not `#chkAddCompare`. Turn the opacity up and you will realise that. You can certainly add the label highlight, (with `label`), but a user won't be able to click on the 'checkbox' that you display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to do this, but you could change the `opacity` of the checkbox to 1 on focus like so:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

That wouldn't change the fact it's actually not visible by the user initially though, unless they key into it by chance with their keyboard!

I'd probably suggest hiding the input with one of [these techniques](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility) instead, writing your markup like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="title"><br>
<label for="title">Male</label>
```

And then styling the `label` with the immediate sibling selector `+` ie

```
[type=checkbox] + label {
  //custom css here 
}
```

The label will get focus instead of the input, and you have much more control over styling :)